# How to create a filter with multiple attributes and multiple options

Tags: go, elasticsearch, filter, logic

I need to create a filter where it may be possible to select multiple attributes and each attribute has multiple options.

This is the data available for consultation (they are in elastic)

the array attributes are the attributes of a single product.

```json
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": "bafa62bf-cc24-4434-943e-6931bb31091f",
            "value": "Black",
            "attributeName": "Color",
            "attributeId": "1c5aae51-a58b-44bc-9073-2c0e4e97bebe"
        },
        {
            "id": "71dd6aeb-03ab-4fae-9ebd-6bf41ab821fa",
            "value": "Brand",
            "attributeName": "Tesla",
            "attributeId": "4c1c9939-6348-42e4-9c07-293587645300"
        },
        {
            "id": "f5fc9a7f-cc11-46fe-aa04-aa0f21ef4f14",
            "value": "Sedan",
            "attributeName": "Type",
            "attributeId": "8cdf4684-3306-4924-92dd-36efc874d416"
        },
        {
            "id": "c666cb4a-4442-4979-aed3-4156a6d92fec",
            "value": "KM",
            "attributeName": "0",
            "attributeId": "975461d4-65a6-47fa-8dc9-595d6def34c5"
        },
        {
            "id": "b3c66548-2a56-47f2-bdfd-2fc043d9d330",
            "value": "2020",
            "attributeName": "Year",
            "attributeId": "f546d055-8c87-45cf-8700-b3d6ca114dbc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I will receive this payload from the frontend, which will be used to filter:

```json
{
    "attributesForFilter": [
        {
            "id": "4c1c9939-6348-42e4-9c07-293587645300",
            "values": [
                "Tesla"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "1c5aae51-a58b-44bc-9073-2c0e4e97bebe",
            "values": [
                "Gray",
                "Black"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "f546d055-8c87-45cf-8700-b3d6ca114dbc",
            "values": [
                "2020"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this example, it must return results that have the value **Tesla** and **Gray** or **Black** and **2020** in the attributes array.

I have already managed to achieve this filter, but I need to return this to frontend, which are the possibilities that the user can select based on the filter applied above

```json
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": "1c5aae51-a58b-44bc-9073-2c0e4e97bebe",
            "name": "Color",
            "source": {
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "6e73fac6-95b3-4665-97ef-8590f9702ddd",
                        "value": "Black"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "71dd6aeb-03ab-4fae-9ebd-6bf41ab821fa",
            "name": "Brand",
            "source": {
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "6e73fac6-95b3-4665-97ef-8590f9702ddd",
                        "value": "Tesla"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "b3c66548-2a56-47f2-bdfd-2fc043d9d330",
            "name": "Year",
            "source": {
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "6e73fac6-95b3-4665-97ef-8590f9702ddd",
                        "value": "2020"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

These are the options and attributes available for the user to continue filtering, but when applying the filter other possibilities are removed, such as the Year attribute, which only returns 2020, but there are more values that must be returned. The same for the other attributes. This happens because the filter excludes possible options, and leaves only the exact options that the frontend passed in `attributesForFilter`

I believe I would need to apply 2 different types of filters, or perhaps modify the attributes data, but I can't find a solution.

It can be done using elastic, or simply searching for products in elastic and applying the logic via code (I'm using golang)

My query for elasticSearch is generated dynamically, the query works as expected, but eliminates the possibilities of returning the possible options for the combination of filters sent by the frontend in `attributesForFilter`

```json
{
    "post_filter": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "status": "active"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "officeId"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "asset"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "categories.id": "6cd9fef8-5c19-4b36-8297-e0fa229df687"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "should": [
                                        {
                                            "bool": {
                                                "should": [
                                                    {
                                                        "nested": {
                                                            "path": "attributes",
                                                            "query": {
                                                                "bool": {
                                                                    "must": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "multi_match": {
                                                                                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
                                                                                "fields": [
                                                                                    "attributes.value^3"
                                                                                ],
                                                                                "query": "Tesla",
                                                                                "type": "phrase_prefix"
                                                                            }
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            "term": {
                                                                                "attributes.attributeId": "71dd6aeb-03ab-4fae-9ebd-6bf41ab821fa"
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "should": [
                                        {
                                            "bool": {
                                                "should": [
                                                    {
                                                        "nested": {
                                                            "path": "attributes",
                                                            "query": {
                                                                "bool": {
                                                                    "must": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "multi_match": {
                                                                                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
                                                                                "fields": [
                                                                                    "attributes.value^3"
                                                                                ],
                                                                                "query": "Black",
                                                                                "type": "phrase_prefix"
                                                                            }
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            "term": {
                                                                                "attributes.attributeId": "1c5aae51-a58b-44bc-9073-2c0e4e97bebe"
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "bool": {
                                                "should": [
                                                    {
                                                        "nested": {
                                                            "path": "attributes",
                                                            "query": {
                                                                "bool": {
                                                                    "must": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "multi_match": {
                                                                                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
                                                                                "fields": [
                                                                                    "attributes.value^3"
                                                                                ],
                                                                                "query": "Gray",
                                                                                "type": "phrase_prefix"
                                                                            }
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            "term": {
                                                                                "attributes.attributeId": "1c5aae51-a58b-44bc-9073-2c0e4e97bebe"
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "should": [
                                        {
                                            "bool": {
                                                "should": [
                                                    {
                                                        "nested": {
                                                            "path": "attributes",
                                                            "query": {
                                                                "bool": {
                                                                    "must": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "multi_match": {
                                                                                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
                                                                                "fields": [
                                                                                    "attributes.value^3"
                                                                                ],
                                                                                "query": "2020",
                                                                                "type": "phrase_prefix"
                                                                            }
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            "term": {
                                                                                "attributes.attributeId": "f546d055-8c87-45cf-8700-b3d6ca114dbc"
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "attributes": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "attributes"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "attributeId": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "attributes.attributeId"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "top_attribute_hits": {
                            "top_hits": {
                                "_source": {
                                    "includes": [
                                        "attributes"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "size": 10
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have filters and aggregations and your aggregations must still provide all possible other values, you need to apply your filter as a [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html#post-filter), so that the filtering is applied after the aggregation phase.

The `query` (hence your filters) reduces the document set to only the ones matching and the aggregations then run on that document set. When using `post_filter`, the hits are filtered only after the aggregations run, hence the aggregations are not impacted by your filter and still aggregate the full data set.

Comment: It seems to be a good alternative, but the aggregation ends up reaching the limit, which by default is 10000, and there is no way to use scroll in top_hits.

Comment: Maybe show your query, it'll probably help

Comment: add the query to the question :)

Comment: Thanks, though I don't see any aggregation or top_hits in your query

Comment: I had left the original query and added the `agg` option with `post_filter`